# Chrome cache - remove single file

Tags: linux, google-chrome, caching

Is there no way to individually view the contents of each of the files under ~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/Cache_Data? I hate it every time I have to remove everything for the sake of one bad player.

The best I can do is grep for a URL and then remove those files. But that didn't work. :(

Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal